# how much is a typical budget for publication costs in a five-year project that requires open access?

Tags: publications, open-access, fees

I need to budget the cost for publication for a European grant that requires open access, either green or gold, and I am struggling to figure out the costs over a five year period. Some multidisciplinary journals can have open access fees up to €10,000 and specialized journals between €2000-4000.

When I add things up it comes to a considerable amount, around €100,000+. I find unreasonable to pay this much for publishing when research money should pay for research, so I am wondering how people budget these publication costs in recent funding application. What are some real costs after 5 years?

I know that in some cases the green open access does not cost because the publisher allows to post the accepted version on a repository within six months. But publishers are becoming more restrictive about this.

Comment: It would help if you specify the field.

Comment: Everything above €500 seems absolutely unreasonable.

Comment: @Arno in my field (theoretical biology), I am not aware of any decent journal that has open access fees below (or even close to) €500.

Comment: @Theoretician My understanding is that the actual costs of running an open access journal frugally boil down to about €200-300 per paper, based on experience in math/CS. A biology journal might be a bit more expensive if they re-typeset everything, but if that actually costs thousands, the effort doesn't seem worth it.

Comment: @Arno Yes, but sadly the journals charge authors way more than what it costs them to process a paper...

Comment: @Arno math journals don't grant waivers to authors from developing countries?

Comment: @ThomasSchwarz I am in life sciences but I specified the costs of open access in my field. Multidisciplinary journals charge a lot and those include your field as well.

Comment: 100,000 USD will pay for 25 publications with a price tag of 4,000 USD each. It sounds like you are planning for a *major* research project. If you are applying for one postdoc and five Ph.D. students over three years, suddenly 100,000 USD for publications sounds like a lot less, no? Also: publication *is* part of research, so with OA, publication costs *are* research costs...

Comment: Depends also on the country. As researcher at a German university, you could get away with zero publishing costs (for the project budget) if you stick to journals covered by suitable open access agreements (such as project DEAL), or if your university provides open access funding from other sources.

Comment: @StephanKolassa, the project is indeed large and over five years. It is not so much the number of publications but if you want to publish 3-4 articles in multidisciplinary journals you are already around the 40k euro mark + all the rest. So essentially the cost of publishing has been offloaded to researchers but publishers still make the same amount of money. So the problem is not been solved really.

Comment: Exactly. It's a case of politicians trying to look good ("We will require OA publishing, because that will democratize research" - which of course *indeed* is good), usually without increasing the budget for funding, so researchers now need to pay for this out of the same amount of funding.